# Open base64 encode file in a browser

Tags: python, base64

From Python (possibly version 3.x) I need to open a new browser's tab with a base64 encoded file as the url.

I've tryed the following:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open(url="data:image/png;base64,MY_BASE64_ENCODED_IMAGE_AS_STRING")
```

but I've got an "error opening location: The specified location is not supported" error.

What's the correct way to do this instead?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a complete traceback?

Comment: @Bach, I've added all the code and the full error displayed to a pastebin, here you go: [link](http://pastebin.com/hiTshJub)

Comment: I'm using `webbrowser.open_new_tab("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAPAAAywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==")` in python 2.6 _(I think)_ and it works, but it opens in _IE_ instead of _Firefox_, which is my default browser.

Comment: @Iulian, It's not working for me, neither with python 2.7 nor 3.4, I get this message "gvfs-open: data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAPAAAywAAAAA‌​AQABAAACAUwAOw==: error opening location: The specified location is not supported" I'm running it under a Linux Mint installation.

Comment: I didn't work in python too much, can't help, sorry.